# changing github account in terminal

Tags: git, powershell, github, terminal, git-bash

how to change my github account in terminal[In the image you can see dhamo2002 which is not my account. i have no idea how this account get connected that is my brother account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxsuT.png)

I have tried so many times using git config and ssh key method but that doesn't work.

All i need is I need to connect my github account 'yuvaraj787' in place of 'dhamo2002'.
I am new to git and github. It will be nice if someone understand what i am saying and help. thanks!.

Comment: provide the information of the machine you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub's offical [Managing multiple accounts](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-personal-account/managing-multiple-accounts) should help.

In [Contributing to multiple accounts using HTTPS and personal access tokens](Contributing to multiple accounts using HTTPS and personal access tokens) section you can learn how to

> use different personal access tokens for each account by configuring Git to store different credentials for each repository.

The section also covers how to clear the current credentials.

Answer (score -1):

### some useful commands:

`git config --global --get user.email`

`git config --global --get user.name`

`git config --global --get-all`

## but to answer your question

```bash
git config --global --unset user.email
git config --global --unset user.name
```

will remove the current profile.

&

```bash
git config --global --add user.email youremail123@gmail.com
git config --global --add user.name YOURUSERNAME123
```

will get your *actual* profile set up :)

###### and to get you the rest of the way:

`git config --global --help`

##### `hint: have your personal access token (PAT) handy for reconfiguring your profile to your shell`

Comment: sorry to say but it doesn't work? again it shows like same

Comment: did you `--unset` the previous account?